# Google Sheets add AND statemnet to IF statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(LEFT(D2,2)="OE",((E2*F2*10)-(E2*1.3))*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD"),"Not Applicable")
```

I have this formula that works fine, but I want to also check another cell, B2, to see if it has a value using `AND`.

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(D2,2)="OE",((E2*F2*10)-(E2*1.3),B2='My Value')),GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD")"Not Applicable"))
```

I have tried this but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it like this:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(D2, 2)="OE", B2="My Value")), 
 ((E2*F2*10)-(E2*1.3))*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD"), "Not Applicable")
```